# How to create text drop shadow in ReportLab?

Tags: python, pdf, reportlab

Using ReportLab's basic drawString methods preferably, or if not any other available ReportLab functionality, how might I create a "drop shadow" effect?

I could draw the string twice I suppose, but that won't make a very nice PDF.
(They are destined for printing, however, not computer consumption, so it may not matter if they strings are doubled.)

Answer (score 0):

The only solution appears to be to print two times on top of each other with different colors and an offset of 1 point in both directions.

```
        style.textColor = 'black'
        f = Frame(column + 1, 
                  row - 1,
                  width, 
                  height)    

        story = [Paragraph(text, style)]

        f.add(KeepInFrame(0, 0, story), canvas)

        style.textColor = 'white'
        f = Frame(column, 
                  row,
                  width, 
                  height)    

        story = [Paragraph(text, style)]

        f.add(KeepInFrame(0, 0, story), canvas)
```

Comment: I know this is what the OP tried to avoid, but I leave it here for other people to use.